# Proving statement similar to primary decomposition theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

$T: V \to V$ is a linear map and $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m$ are distinct scalars. I'm trying to prove that the following two statements are equivalent:

$$(T- \lambda_1 I)...(T - \lambda_m I) = 0$$

And

$$V = \bigoplus_{i=1} ^m V_i$$

Where $V_i = ker (T - \lambda_i I)$

Now one direction is pretty simple, for the other direction my thoughts on proving this are to use induction on $m$ and then using the fact that the factors are coprime I can use Bezout's lemma to get the result.

However I am a bit unsure whether induction actually proves this, given that my definition for a vector space being an internal direct sum is that each vector is expressible uniquely as an element form each summand.

Thanks

Comment: The statement you're proving by induction is to hold for *every* vector space $V$, so when you do the inductive step you're applying the result to a subspace of the original given $V$.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow what the issue is there, would you mind elaborating a bit?

Answer (score 1):

```
Your statement holds. In fact, if V=directsum Vi, where Vi=Ker(T-λi), 
if you take a basis from each subspace Vi, then on the elements vj of such base
(T−λ1I)...(T−λmI)(vj)=(T-λ1I)...(T-jI)(vj)=0 , because the endomorphisms T-λi commute.
Then, the union of the basis of the Vi-s is a base of V, on which (T−λ1I)...(T−λmI) is
null, so (T−λ1I)...(T−λmI)=0.
Viceversa, if (T−λ1I)...(T−λmI)=0, since the λi-s are all different, they are coprime, 
and (T−λ1I)...(T−λmI)\in I(T), the ideal of all polynomials p(t)\in  such that P(T)=0, so,
due to the primary decomposition, v=directsum Vi=directsum Vi.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am looking for a proof that doesn't rely on the primary decomposition theorem as that is essentially what I am trying to prove